# How can I redirect example.com/username to Instagram app directly open from deep link?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, apache, apache2, deeplinks

I'm trying to redirect from `example.com/username​` to Instagram deep link `instagram://user?username=anyusername`

Here is my htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)? example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ instagram://user?username=%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

But it redirects to `http://example.com/instagram://user?username=/instagram://user`

Comment: The code you've posted would break with a 500 Error since you have an erroneous space in the _CondPattern_?! However, even if corrected, it would not trigger the redirect you describe - something else is doing that! (But `https://instagram.com/username` looks kinda "correct"??) Ordinarily, Apache will see a _substitution_ like `instagram://user...` as a _relative_ URL since it won't understand the `instagram` protocol, unless you have specifically installed something on the server that enables this? I would expect the above to redirect to `http://example.com/instagram://user?username=/foo` (?)

Comment: Not that I've tried it with Apache, but I'd expect anything matching `[a-z]+://.*` to be treated as an absolute URL.   I don't think most absolute/relative URL recognition relies on a list of recognized protocols.

Comment: @MrWhite Yes it redirects to http://example.com/instagram://user?username=/instagram://user and I edited the description. Now I'm expecting an answer of my question.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller It's actually a mod_rewrite thing. mod_rewrite specifically (rather than Apache in general) validates the scheme/protocol against a recognised list of schemes in order to determine whether the substitution string maps to an absolute URL. More details in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)? example\.com$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^ instagram://user?username=%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
> ```

*Aside:* You have an erroneous *space* in the *CondPattern* in the `RewriteCond` directive. This will result in an immediate 500 error, so I assume this is not present in your actual code and is just (somehow) a typo in your question? It should read `^(www\.)?example\.com` (removing the trailing `$` allows the directive to match fully qualified host names that end in a dot).

However, as you are finding, this won't redirect as intended anyway. mod_rewrite (specifically mod_rewrite and not Apache in general) validates the *scheme* (if any) on the *substitution*. If it's not one of a [predefined short list of schemes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24136175/how-to-handle-mod-rewrite-with-a-custom-url-scheme) and does not start with a slash, it is seen as a *relative* URL. mod_rewrite then prefixes the scheme and hostname from the request, resulting in the malformed redirect you are experiencing.

(I also imagine you don't require the slash prefix on the username, which comes from the `REQUEST_URI` server variable?)

Instead, you could use a mod_alias `RedirectMatch` directive, which does not validate the scheme and sends the URL as written. For example:

```
RedirectMatch 302 /(.+) instagram://user?username=$1
```

However, this doesn't check the hostname on the request, like you were doing with mod_rewrite. Would that be a requirement? Do you have multiple domains on this one account?

Also, such URLs probably won't be recognised by desktop browsers, if that is a concern.

Reference:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24136175/how-to-handle-mod-rewrite-with-a-custom-url-scheme

---

See also this related question if you are having problems with the directory index:
[My website keeps redirect to the "index.php" account on Instagram app](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/108506/my-website-keeps-redirect-to-the-index-php-account-on-instagram-app)

Comment: Now with Apache 2.4 you can put an `If` directive around the `RedirectMatch`:  `<If "req('Host') == 'www.example.com'">...</If>`  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if