# My website keeps redirect to the "index.php" account on Instagram app

Tags: htaccess, redirects, deeplinks

My htaccess code allows `example.com/username` redirect to any username on Instagram app. But when I open `example.com` it redirects to an Instagram account called `index.php`. 
How can I fix it?
Here is my htaccess

```
RedirectMatch 302 /(.+) instagram://user?username=$1
```

Comment: Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: @MrWhite No. I don't have any other directives in my .htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably due to mod_dir issuing a subrequest for the directory index (ie. `index.php`).

You can try adding a negative lookahead to the regex to specifically exclude requests for `index.php`. For example:

```
RedirectMatch 302 /(?!index\.php)(.+) instagram://user?username=$1
```

**UPDATE:** If you are now having a problem with `index.html` (another possible directory index) then you can exclude this as well:

```
RedirectMatch 302 /(?!index\.php|index\.html)(.+) instagram://user?username=$1
```

Or disable directory indexes altogether and redirect *everything* (change `.+` to `.*`). For example:

```
DirectoryIndex disabled
RedirectMatch 302 /(.*) instagram://user?username=$1
```

However, this will redirect even when no *username* is given.

---

To avoid conflicts with your existing site, it would probably be preferable to make this "instagram" URL unique, so it doesn't *override* your existing URLs. For example: `example.com/instagram/<username>`. You could then simplify the above directive to:

```
RedirectMatch 302 /instagram/(.+) instagram://user?username=$1
```

Or, you could even reduce it to something like `example.com/i/<username>` - if that is still unique.

```
RedirectMatch 302 /i/(.+) instagram://user?username=$1
```

Comment: It is now redirecting to "index.html" username of Instagram

Comment: Does `index.php` and/or `index.html` exist? Anyway, you can exclude both of these, or disable `DirectoryIndex` altogether. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Or... what do you want to happen when accessing the bare domain `example.com/` (ie. no username)? Do you still want to redirect? Or serve a local file instead? I've updated my answer.

Comment: I just want to show hompage of my website. When I open example.com and  your `RedirectMatch 302 /(?!index\.php|index\.html)(.+) instagram://user?username=$1` working

Comment: But there is a problem happening. When I open any page of my website like `example.com/about.html`, it is   redirects to `about.html` username on Instagram. Do you have any solution for it?

Comment: Yes, it will. You can either make more exceptions to include in the above directive - but this depends on your site and the type of URLs being requested. Is it all static `.html`, `.css` and `.js` files etc? Or, the preferred solution might be to change your instagram URL to something unique. eg `example.com/instagram/<username>` or even `example.com/i/<username>`, if you wanted something shorter and `example.com/i/` was unique. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yes they are all static `.html`,`.css` and `.js` . And I have just tried `example.com/i/<username` but it is redirecting to `i/username`.

Comment: With the updated code?

Comment: oh sorry. Updated code is working. Thank you very much